# Kernel security modules: i_security in struct inode

Tags: linux, security, kernel, inode, linux-security-module

my question is probably again pretty simple, but I did not find anything. I am writing a Linux Security Module. As you might know the struct inode in the kernel contains one field i_security to save security relevant information for the LSM. Now just to make sure: Is it safe to assume that no user (not even root) will be able to read or write this value, i.e. can this value really be accessed only from kernel space?

The reason for my question is, that it is obvious that some inode data can be accessed from userspace (through systemcalls I guess, but still using chmod etc. you are able to change some values in an inode) and now I wonder if that doesn't mean, that all inode data (also the i_security) can be accessed from user space somehow.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use grep or ack to scan kernel code for `i_security`, and you can find it is modified only by files under `security/` directory, and cannot be modified by user applications, since they have no direct access to the `i_security` field.